# Why doesn't a parent div have the same size as a contained image?

Tags: html, css

I've got a situation here that I can't put my head around.

```css
.navigation {
  position: absolute;
}

.navigation > img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation previous">
    <img src="http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/MinorCatImages/033256AM.png">
</div>
```

Why does the freaking div get the size of the png's original width? How can I solve this? I need the parent div to have its children width and height without explicit setting these properties.

https://jsfiddle.net/gvng79s5/

Comment: give the image `display:block` maybe?

Comment: css rules don't flow uphill. making your img 50% wide won't magically make the parent also 50% smaller.

Comment: When you set `position: absolute;` you also have to set `width: 100%`, or the div will collapse to fill the minimum possible width.

Comment: @MarcB the `div` is positioned absolute, so the initial (if there is not element inside)  would be `0`. If you set the `img` to a fixed with of `25px` then the would also have a with of `25px`.

Comment: yes, but that's only because you used a fixed width. OP's got a relative width, and it's relative to the parent. The browser would enter an infinite recursive loop if the parent adjusted itself to the child. e.g. parent renders at 100px, so child is rendered at 50px. but hey, parent has to be 50% as well, so it drops to 50px, and hey, now the child has to be 50%, so it drops to 25px, blah blah blah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's because of `% percentage` that's true. Default div `width` value is `auto`, so now if you are defining your child element in `% percentage` then in that situation your parent calculates it's width according to the width of child element when assigned in `% percentage` i.e. `100%` of child to parent.

Over-here we are assigning `50% width` to `child element` and `parent` doesn't have any width. But it assigns it automatically as child needs to be 50% of parent. whereas in `px` both are same.

```css
/*Using Percentage*/
.navigation {
    position: absolute;
        background:#111;
      }

   .navigation > img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 50%;
   }
/*using pixels*/
 .previous {
    position: absolute;
                background:#111;
         }

   .previous > img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="navigation"><img src="http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/MinorCatImages/033256AM.png">
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="previous">
<img src="http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/MinorCatImages/033256AM.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you apply your navigation style to the image, not the div.

If you want your image to take the size of the div, you can set `height` and `width` of your div as you prefer, and give `width: 100%` to your image:

```
.navigation {
    width: 20%; //change it
    height: 20%; //change it
}

.navigation > img {         
    width: 100%;
}
```

Forked your Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8g3mewxk/).